# What programming stack should I be using to quickly develop a web application with sophisticated gui?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, web-applications, frameworks

I am developing a webapp that communicates with a backend which performs intensive numerical calculations and then displays the output nicely on screen. I need the web-end to be sophisticated and look good.

Any suggestions about the programming stack I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose a framework, you already know at least a bit about - since that would make you more productive. Some suggestions:

- [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/)
- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)
- [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)

Answer (score 0):

By stack do you mean scripting language or CMS?

If former I'd say PHP, if latter, I'd guess at Droopal but CMS isn't really my thing.

I guess you mean all of them. Depends how much effort you want to put in. Adobe is 'flashy' but pricey and a lot of work, I'd rather hand code so I know how to recreate/reformat it.

Bluefish wasn't much use to me. But Kompozer is worth a look if you have a $0 budget?

Comment: Can I guess? Is PHP the only language (for web apps) you are familiar with?

Comment: Err, by familiar I take it... Yes it is, if that. Did ASP years ago but years is a lifetime ago innit?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the immensely supported, documented, and professionalism of Visual Studio 2010/ASP.NET MVC3/SQL Server 2008.

You ask for suggestions and that's mine. The Razor syntax in MVC 3 makes it so easy for developers to integrate server code within their front end to do extra manipulation, and the .NET platform is easily capable of doing numerical calculations server side.

You could also probably get a lot of stuff done in the database itself.